# i want to send SMS from Android application using SMS manager

Tags: android, smsmanager

I have tried sending but the SMS is automatically sent without getting known. I want to send SMS with field of **To** to be predefined from my code and can get the inbuilt SMS APP.

My Code

```
holder.SMS.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.e("sssssss", "aaaaaaaa");

                try {
//                  View view = (View) v.getParent();
//                  TextView number = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.phone);
//                  String selected_mobile_sms = number.getText().toString();
//                  Log.e("sssssss", "ssssssss" + selected_mobile_sms);

                    // sendSMS();

                    SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
                    sm.sendTextMessage("tel:121", null, "test message", null,
                            null);


//                      
//                  
//                   Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
//                   sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "");
//                  //
//                   sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
//                   activity.startActivity(sendIntent);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Comment: `sm.sendTextMessage("9186229644", null, "my content", null, null)` try this

Comment: this is as same as what i did

Comment: you are using `SmsManager` right? I am not sure i understand your problem correctly. http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-send-sms-message-in-android/. check this might help.

Comment: @Anchit : no. you don't need the `tel:`. that's the difference.

Comment: @Raghunandan what i want is i want to send SMS using SMSManager but like to invoke built in sms sending Feature of android phone with destination field defined from code.

Comment: @Anchit check the link posted has both examples.

Comment: @njzk2 but that does not make any difference to execution for the code. this is what i want to say

Comment: need `SEND_SMS` permission. did you added this to your manifest?

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />`

Comment: @ramin i have already provided all the permissions that are required

Comment: @Raghunandan i already referred the link you have provided. Thanks

Comment: @Anchit so whats is the problem your facing implementing it.

Comment: @Raghunandan sir what i want is to fetch number onto which i want to send sms from my code and then need to display the number in the destination field of inbuilt sms service. i think now i need to design a separate UI for the same

Answer (score 0):

```
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
    {
        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);
    }

Call this method like 

btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {

            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                sendSMS("5556", "Hello my friends!");

            }
        });
```

Add these into your manifest:

Comment: sorry the permissions are <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
              <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>

Answer (score 0):

You can Use this method To Send Message:

```
string number = "+987654321";
string message = "Sim1 سلام فردین" + "تست برنامه نویسی";
Intent i = new Intent(ApplicationContext, this.Class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(ApplicationContext, 0, i, 0);
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.GetSmsManagerForSubscriptionId(3);

sms.SendTextMessage(number, null, message, pIntent, null);
```