# Manipulate Native SMS App

Tags: android, android-intent

Im sending SMS in my application using `Intent` like

```
Intent si= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
si.putExtra("sms_body", "some text"); 
si.putExtra("address", "123456789"); 
si.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
startActivity(si);
```

is there a way i can restrict the user from adding any additional text, disable the native application's `EditText` area, is that possible...

Answer (score 1):

instead of Opening SMS APP via intent Why not use SMS Manager( method sendTextMessage ) and send SMS from your app..

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html

note requires permission : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SEND_SMS

Comment: i know but then i have to handle the message send not sent scenarios myself which i dont want to :) so im looking for a short cut

Comment: Here you go :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17672634/i-want-to-send-sms-from-android-application-using-sms-manager